# Unable insert moment to Google+ using access token from mobile client

Tags: ruby, google-plus

Android/iOS client sends to server API access_token and message.

I'm trying to share but with no luck, google responses with 'Invalid credentials'.

I was trying to add requestvisibleactions to client:

```
client = Google::APIClient.new(requestvisibleactions: ['https://schemas.google.com/AddActivity'])
```

And same to client.execute.

```
class GoogleSharer
  def self.share(access_token, message, resource)
    client = Google::APIClient.new
    client.authorization.update_token!(access_token: access_token)
    plus = client.discovered_api('plus', 'v1')
    moment = {
       type: ['http://schemas.google.com/AddActivity'],
       target: { name: message, url: get_resource_url(resource) }
    }
    response = client.execute(api_method: plus.moments.insert, parameters: {collection: 'vault', userId: 'me'}, body_object: moment).body
    a = 10
  end
end
```

Please advise. Thanks.